# Blender opens to graphical scramble when launched from .desktop

Tags: nvidia, graphics, blender

Hi so the issue I'm having is that after I've downloaded from the blender site and extracted the blender .tar onto my ubuntu machine (22.04) and attempted to set it up it to launch from my applications for easy launching, the program launches into what I can only describe as a graphically scrambled mess, essentially unreadable.
I followed this tutorial closely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A0rUATuGc4&t=196s and have triple checked all the steps involved and have reviewed the text file and can find no error in the way that I edited the .desktop file. Everything is entered as it should be for it to work but for some reason, it isnt. I am using the most recent nvidia graphics driver could this be a driver issue? Blender launches just fine from the blender executable file just not from the blender.desktop file. I am also unable to embed image files since I am a new user to this site.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
GenericName=3D modeler
GenericName[ar]=3D المنمذج ثلاثي الأبعاد
GenericName[ca]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[cs]=3D modelování
GenericName[da]=3D-modellering
GenericName[de]=3D-Modellierer
GenericName[el]=Μοντελοποιητής 3D
GenericName[es]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[et]=3D modelleerija
GenericName[fi]=3D-mallintaja
GenericName[fr]=Modeleur 3D
GenericName[gl]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[hu]=3D modellező
GenericName[it]=Modellatore 3D
GenericName[ja]=3D モデラー
GenericName[lt]=3D modeliavimas
GenericName[nb]=3D-modellering
GenericName[nl]=3D-modeller
GenericName[pl]=Modelowanie 3D
GenericName[pt_BR]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[ro]=Arhitect 3D
GenericName[ru]=Редактор 3D-моделей
GenericName[tr]=3D modelleyici
GenericName[uk]=Редактор 3D-моделей
GenericName[wa]=Modeleu 3D
GenericName[zh_CN]=3D 建模
GenericName[zh_TW]=3D 模型
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Comment[ar]=3D النمذجة، الرسوم المتحركة، والتجسيد، وما بعد الإنتاج
Comment[ast]=Modeláu 3D, animación, renderizáu y postproducción
Comment[eu]=3D modelatzea, animazioa, errendatzea eta post-produkzioa
Comment[be]=Праграма прасторавага мадэлявання, анімацыі, апрацоўкі відэа і давядзення відэапрадукцыі
Comment[bn]=ত্রিমাত্রিক মডেল, অ্যানিমেশন, রেন্ডারিং এবং পোস্ট-উৎপাদন
Comment[bs]=3D modeliranje, animacija, obrada i postprodukcija
Comment[bg]=3D моделиране, анимиране, рендиране и пост-продукция
Comment[ca]=Modelat 3D, animació, renderització i post-producció
Comment[ca@valencia]=Modelat 3D, animació, renderització i post-producció
Comment[crh]=3B modelleme, animasyon, işleme ve son üretim
Comment[cs]=3D modelování, animace, rederování a postprodukce
Comment[da]=3D-modellering, animation, rendering og efterbehandling
Comment[de]=3D-Modellierung, Animation, Rendering und Nachbearbeitung
Comment[nl]=3d-modelleren, animeren, renderen en post-productie
Comment[el]=Μοντελοποίηση 3D, κινούμενα σχέδια, αποτύπωση και οργάνωση διαδικασίας μετά-την-παραγωγή
Comment[eo]=3D-modelado, animacio, renderado kaj postproduktado
Comment[es]=Modelado 3D, animación, renderizado y post-producción
Comment[et]=Kolmemõõtmeline modelleerimine, animeerimine, esitlemine ja järeltöötlemine
Comment[fi]=3D-mallinnus, -animaatiot, -renderöinti ja -tuotanto
Comment[fr]=Modélisation 3D, animation, rendu et post-production
Comment[fr_CA]=Modélisation 3D, animation, rendu et post-production
Comment[gl]=Modelado 3D, animación, renderizado e postprodución
Comment[hu]=3D modellek és animációk létrehozása és szerkesztése
Comment[is]=Þrívíddarmódel, hreyfimyndir, myndgerð og frágangur myndskeiða
Comment[it]=Modellazione 3D, animazione, rendering e post-produzione
Comment[ja]=3Dモデリング、アニメーション、レンダリング、ポストプロダクションのツール
Comment[ko]=3D 
Comment[lt]=3D modeliavimas, animacijų kūrimas, atvaizdavimas ir tobulinimas
Comment[lv]=3D modelēšana, animācija, renderēšana un pēcapstrāde
Comment[ms]=Pemodelan, animasi, penerapan dan post-produksi 3D
Comment[nb]=3D-modellering, animasjon, rendering og postproduksjon
Comment[oc]=Modelizacion 3D, animacion, rendut e post-produccion
Comment[pl]=Modelowanie 3D, animacja, renderowanie i postprodukcja
Comment[pt]=Modelação 3D, animação, renderização e pós-produção
Comment[pt_BR]=Modelagem 3D, animação, renderização e pós-produção
Comment[ro]=Modelare, animare, afișare și post-producție 3D
Comment[ru]=3D-моделирование, анимация, рендеринг и компоновка
Comment[sl]=3D modeliranje, animacija, izrisovanje in nadaljnje obdelovanje
Comment[sq]=Animacion i modeleve 3D, rregullim dhe më pas prodhim
Comment[sr]=3Д моделовање, анимација, исцртавање и постпродукција
Comment[sv]=3d-modellering, animering, rendering och efterbehandling
Comment[ta]=முப்பரிமாண ஒப்புருவாக்கம், அசைவூட்டம், காட்சியாக்கம் மற்றும் உருவாக்கத்துக்கு பிந்தைய செயல்பாடுகள்
Comment[tg]=Моделсозии 3D, аниматсия, пешниҳод ва истеҳсоли баъдӣ
Comment[tr]=3B modelleme, animasyon, işleme ve son üretim
Comment[uk]=Програма просторового моделювання, анімації, обробки відео та доведення відеопродуктів
Comment[vi]=Tạo hình mẫu 3D, hoạt họa, dựng hình và các công việc hậu kỳ
Comment[wa]=Modelaedje 3D, animåcion, rindou eyet après-produccion
Comment[zh_HK]=3D
Comment[zh_CN]=3D 
Comment[zh_TW]=3D
Keywords=3d;cg;modeling;animation;painting;sculpting;texturing;video editing;video tracking;rendering;render engine;cycles;game engine;python;
Exec=/home/zach/Downloads/programs/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64/blender %f
Icon=/home/zach/Downloads/programs/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64/blender.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

Comment: post contents of .desktop? also how are you launching the executable?

Comment: The site won't allow me to attach images to my question as my account is still too new. To launch the executable, I double click on the exe file in the blender directory that was created when the file was .tar was extracted. But if someone were to say.. upvote my question, it would make me reputable enough to be able to post some screenshots of what I am describing as well as the contents of the .desktop text file!!! ;) ;) ;) ;) ....... ;)

Comment: Do not paste images of text; copy-paste the contents of the file and output from your terminal into a code block.

Comment: updated. sorry it's my first day

Comment: The "non-default GPU" thing may be throwing it off; do you know which GPU it uses when you double-click the executable? Also, you may want to remove all the unnecessary lines from the .desktop file, so that it's easier to read/debug (such as all the translations of everything)

Comment: also, is there a reason you aren't just installing with `sudo apt install blender`?

Comment: what GPU do you have, and do you have the correct drivers for it?

Comment: @Esther 
1. yes it is using my Rtx 3080 when the exe is used to launch it directly
2. I want to use to most recent version of blender which isn't contained within the apt repo
3. I am using an evga ftw3 rtx3080 as my primary gpu and I am using proprietary  NVIDIA driver 515 (proprietary, tested)

Would you recommend switching the argument to false?

Comment: I would recommend removing them altogether, and seeing if that helps. If it can figure out which GPU to use when you double-click, it can figure it out when you launch with a .desktop.

Comment: @Nmath I meant exe as an abbreviated form of "Type executable (application/x-executable)" (the term executable is obtained by right clicking on the "blender" file contained within the .tar folder which i downloaded, selecting properties and is listed under file type) 
I apologize for the confusion. It is an executable file  contained within the .tar file that I downloaded by web from the blender website and extracted into my /home folder. No i don't want to use snap for blender because I experience significant performance downsides in all aspects of the program when doing so.

Comment: @Esther Hey it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it to work by opening the blender.desktop file and removing these 2 lines of code from the file:

```
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
```

after removing the lines from the blender.desktop file everything works as it should and blender opens just fine from the applications browser. I think this will be useful for anyone who wants to have the latest version of blender installed onto their ubuntu machine from the source and without having to utilize snaps.

Thanks again to Esther for providing the answer!